# Pause form from submitting with javascript

Tags: php, javascript, html, form-submit

I am trying to do a submit form with photos. After the user loads the photos he presses the submit button, I want the form to pause for 10 seconds, animate a progress bar for those 10 seconds and then submit the form, can you guys say what I did wrong, it doesn't seem to submit the form after 10 seconds. 
Here is the code:

HTML:

```
<form action="uploadpic.php" method="post" id="upload_form">
<input type="text" name="title" id="title">
<p id="title_p">Title</p>

<hr />

<input type="text" name="theme" id="picture_theme" size="40"/>
<p id="theme">Picture Theme<img src="../simages/info.gif" id="info" width="12" height="12" style="margin-left:10px;"></p>
<hr />

<div class="custom-upload">
    <input type="file" name="picture" id="true_pic" />
    <div class="fake-file">
        <input disabled="disabled" >
    </div>
</div>
<p id="upload_pic">Upload picture</p>​

<input type="submit" name="submit" id="submit" value="Upload" />
</form>
```

JAVASCRIPT:

```
form = document.getElementById("upload_form");
    size=1;
    form.onsubmit = function()
    {
        if (size < 10)
        {
            setTimeout(delayedSubmit,1000); 
        }
        return false;
    }
    function delayedSubmit() {
        size++;
            if (size<5)
            {
                setTimeout(delayedSubmit,1000);
                alert("Counting "+size);    
            }
            else
            {
                alert("Form submitted");
                form.submit();
            }
    }
```

PHP :

```
<?php

if ($_POST['submit'])
{
    $title = $_POST['title'];
    $theme = $_POST['picture_theme'];
    echo $title," ",$theme; 
}




 ?>
```

I can tell that the form won't submit anything by the fact that the php variables won't show anything, and then page doesn't load.

Comment: Put `console.log(form)` before submitting the form, what does it show?

Comment: Make sure you assign the variable `form` after the DOM is completely loaded.

Comment: That's wrong. If `form` weren't assigned correctly, the timer wouldn't be running in the first place (I assume that part is working, right?). So it seems like something is reassigning `form` after you start the timer. You should capture it in a closure variable.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When a form has a button with the name and/or id "submit", it won't work anymore (my old post was wrong).

So what you need to do is to change the name/id of the button:

```
<input type="submit" name="submit-button" id="submit-button" value="Upload" />
```

Remember: You need to change your PHP, too:

```
if ($_POST['submit'])
{
    $title = $_POST['title'];
    $theme = $_POST['picture_theme'];
    echo $title," ",$theme; 
}
```

to

```
if ($_POST['submit-button'])
{
    $title = $_POST['title'];
    $theme = $_POST['picture_theme'];
    echo $title," ",$theme; 
}
```

Comment: "When a form has a submit-button, form.submit() doesn't work anymore" - can you explain why do you think that?

Comment: I tried your method but now when I click the button nothing happens... I am confused..

Comment: @tborychowski It's because `form.submit` no longer points to the `submit( )` function of the `form` object, it points to the element with name "submit".

Comment: @CioroianuDenis: damnit, I'm slow today :D you also need to change the ID - try again (and mind the ID-change).

Comment: the pages is loading now and the value from the fields disappear which means the page is getting loaded, but the php values won't echo anything.

Comment: @CioroianuDenis because the name has changed, you need to modify your php, too -  `$_POST['submit']` would now be `$_POST['submit-button']`

Comment: Thanks guys. What was I thinking :-). However that seems to be the case not only with the name but also with ID of the button (id also cannot be "submit")

Comment: @tborychowski: Yeah, I changed both, but forgot the mention both. Thanks, I'll edit my post (again)!

Comment: @CioroianuDenis: I think `submit-button` will only be included in the form submission if the form was submitted by clicking that button. (This allows you to have multiple submit buttons in a form and determine on the server which one was clicked to submit it.) Thus when you submit the form via JavaScript, `submit-button` won't be in your `$_POST` array. You could try doing `document.getElementById('submit-button').click()` instead of `form.submit()`.

Comment: Thank you Paul D. Waite, it worked on your method, thank you very much :)

Comment: @CioroianuDenis: What do you want to achieve by deleting and reposting your commen several times?

Comment: well I just wanted to edit the comment but since there is no edit button I deleted it and reposted it.

Comment: @CioroianuDenis ah, okay :D I just wondered, because I get a notification everytime :)

Answer (score 1):

I'd simplify the javascript:

```
form = document.getElementById("upload_form");
size=0;

form.onsubmit = delayedSubmit;

function delayedSubmit () {
    if (++size < 5) {
        alert("Counting "+size);    
        setTimeout(delayedSubmit,1000);
        return false;
    } 
    alert("Form submitted");
    form.submit();
}
```

And - of course - remove (or change) id and name from the submit button, e.g:

```
<input type="submit" value="Upload" />
```

e.g.: http://jsbin.com/equyit/1/edit

Comment: another question, I saw that if I return false one time the values from the inputs will get lost, how can I avoid that?

Comment: @CioroianuDenis It must be something else. Inputs are "read" when the form is submitted, so - in the example above - the values should be sent correctly. The "return false" would not matter.